# creating user input in html5/javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have been able to generate several arcs using html/javascript/canvas.
The lines of code below as you will see draw the arcs as my final result image.

What I would now like to do is have a user interface that will define these arcs instead of coding them line by line manually, the only variables in each arc is rad, sAng, eAng and Sector size (my stroke width).

My aim is to draw anything from 2 to 30 arcs number to be defined by the user.

My end goal is an image similar to this: [arcs final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Z5qK.jpg)

```
// centre is  x    y   rad sAng eAng antiC  line    fill   Sector size
//arc1
drawArc(447, 426, 005, 00, 360, false, "blue", "white", 11);
//arc2
drawArc(447, 426, 210, 9, 41, false, "blue", "white", 58);
//arc3
drawArc(447, 426, 280, 9, 90, false, "blue", "white", 78);
//arc4
drawArc(447, 426, 210, 95, 130, false, "blue", "white", 222);
//arc5
drawArc(447, 426, 200, 140, 189, false, "blue", "white", 242);
//arc6
drawArc(447, 426, 280, 190, 235, false, "blue", "white", 82);
//arc7
drawArc(447, 426, 380, 00, 180, false, "blue", "white", 42);
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried the HTML input element? You would be able to read its value and act appropriately.

Comment: Hey! Welcome to stackoverflow! What exactly is your problem and what are you waiting us to help you with ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response, I am wanting to know if a user can define the amount of arcs that are drawn and what tool or code i could use to add the information that the user has control over which would be the name of the arc, and the numbers in the arc, sAng, eAng and Sector size columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get input from the user, you can either use [HTML input elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) or, if you don't want to use HTML, the [JavaScript prompt function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt), with the latter seldom being used in real applications.

Here's an example of HTML input tags:

```
<html>
  <body>
    Name: <input type="text" id="user_name">
    <br>
    Age: <input type="number" id="user_age" min="0">
    <br>
    <button id="button">Submit</button>
    <script>
      document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', e=>{
        var name = document.getElementById('user_name').value,
            age  = parseInt(document.getElementById('user_age').value);
        alert(`Hello, ${name}! In ten years you will be ${age + 10} years old.`);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript prompt function can be used as such:

```
var name = prompt("What's your name?"),
    age  = prompt('How old are you?');
```

Comment: I can see how that displays the users name and age upon a button press, can you now have another form that pops up to add another users name and age on a line below the one already entered?

Comment: Definitely. You could either use the same form again, by drawing an arc for every time the button is clicked without removing any previous arcs. This way the user can add how many arcs they'd want to add by changing the input elements values, clicking the button and repeating. The other possibility would be to use the document.createElement() function to create new input fields or the Node.cloneNode() function to make duplicates of the first input elements when the button has been pressed.

Comment: many thanks i will give this a try and let you all know how i get on.